# how to use include statement in a for loop (range) helm

Tags: kubernetes-helm, helm3

I am trying to use an include statement in helm range, but

```
I am getting an error can't evaluate field Values in type string.
```

test.yaml

```
spec: 
  rules: 
    {{- range .Values.tests }}
      - host: {{ . }}
        http:
          paths:
          - backend:
              service:
                name: test-{{ $.Values.somename }}
                port:
                  number: {{- include "testit.get_port" }}
            path: /
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
    {{- end }}
```

and _helper.tpl is this

```
{{- define "testit.get_port" }}
  {{- if (eq .Values.somtest "test1") }}5000{{- else }}80{{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

I know for using values, you have to use a $ sign if it is used in range loop. How about include, what should i use there

Comment: ```{{- include "testit.get_port" $ }}  ```. And may you provide values.yaml and export output?

Comment: it says expected map, got a string error

Answer (score 0):

You didn't include any parameter to the `include` call, so the template is getting `nil` as its parameter.  Inside a `range` loop, you probably need to pass the `$` top-level object

```yaml
number: {{- include "testit.get_port" $ }}
#                                     ^
```